# maintain the user input string in to db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Probably simple question but it has been a long time since i work with UI,

I have a textarea that the user can enter his input. I'm saving the input into sql server table.
when i want to display the input all the breaks that the user entered are gone.
I remember there was a way to replace `char 13` with `<br/>` (did that with classic ASP)

I wonder if there is any better way to over come this problem with asp.net,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the line-breaks are indeed stored in your DB, you could always surround the html when you display it within `<pre>` tags to preserve the line breaks in the display.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow. what do you mean "display it with tags"

Comment: sorry. the actual tag in my answer got interpreted as a literal tag and wasn't being displayed in the answer. see my corrected answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.Replace` to replace the \r and/or \n characters with `<br/>`. Of course you'll probably want to do that on the way out, not on the way in.

Comment: i thought asp.net will have more elegant way... seems to me like a very common task ?!?!